# How to find the dot product of large matrices (but the result would be of moderate size) faster in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a 500-by-40K matrix `A` and a 40K-element vector `q` in the form of numpy arrays. By estimation it would take 16 minutes to compute the **dot product** of them by `A.dot(q)`. Because there are 50K `q` that I need to do this computation with (which is a lot), I would like to reduce the computing time as much as possible.

Are more efficient better ways to compute the dot product of `A` and `q`, or better, of `A` and `Q`=[q1, ... , qn]? **Scipy** seems to provide a solution in [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.blas.html), but I don't quite understand how should I approach my problem here. Can anybody help me out here?

```
from time import process_time
t1 = process_time()
A[0,:].dot(q)
t2 = process_time()
print("Estimated Total Time:", (t2-t1)*A.shape[0]/60)
```

Comment: `A.dot(b)` is generally as good as you'll get.  Sometimes the arrays are large enough that  doing it in chunks will save time.  For full arrays memory management can chew into any time savings.

Comment: *"I have a 500-by-40K matrix A and a 40K-element vector q in the form of numpy arrays. By estimation it would take 16 minutes to compute the dot product of them by A.dot(q)."*  This is your first sentence, and you say `q` is a 40K-element vector.  In that case, `A.dot(q)` should not take 16 minutes.  On my 6 year old laptop, it takes 4.9 milliseconds. *"Because there are 50K q..."*  Ah, so *that's* what takes 16 minutes.  A little copy-editing of the first few sentences might avoid some initial confusion for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of what you can do:

```
Q = np.hstack((q1, q2, q3, q4, ...))
B = np.dot(A, Q)
```

in the output, column `i` of `B`(`B[:,i]`) is the product of `A` and `q_i`. This should be fairly fast, even for your required array sizes. It should not even take as long as you mentioned, probably in a matter of a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient memory to hold `A` and all the `q` vectors, it should not take 16 minutes to compute those products, if you put all the `q` vectors into an array `Q` and call `A.dot(Q)`.

This is on a laptop with a 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB memory.  I'm using the interactive Python shell `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [3]: A = rng.normal(size=(500, 40_000)).astype(np.float32)

In [4]: Q = np.ones((40_000, 50_000), dtype=np.float32)

In [5]: %timeit A.dot(Q)
7.79 s ± 235 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That's under 8 seconds--pretty far from 16 minutes!

If you *don't* have sufficient memory, it could take a lot longer, as the OS might start swapping out memory to disk.